# Flutter change size of one element in GridView widget

Tags: flutter

I wondered how I could customize one GridView element like this UI:

[image: != spacing between them]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridViewBuilder` and return a different `Widget` for a particular index.

```
GridView.builder(
    itemCount: no.of.items,
    gridDelegate:   new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                   crossAxisCount: GridViewRow),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     If (index == 1){
          return Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
           ) ;
      }
    return Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
           ) ;
} 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.3),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
            Image.asset(
              "/assets/your_image",
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Kiwi'),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Text('Gurugram Mandi'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("90"),
                      Text("Port Quintal"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text("View Prices"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5)
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Here is the structure, of course with the GridView some hard coded value are useless. You can start with that and make the design change.